# cordova-plugin-facebook on phonegap doesn't open pop

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

I am using the cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin on my Phonegapp Cordova project and although the pop opens when I test the app on the browser it does nothing when I compile it and run on a mobile phone. 
What am I missing ??

Code being used:

```
logInWithFacebook = function() {
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
       FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                var result_holder = document.getElementById('result_friends');
                result_holder.innerHTML = response.name;
         });
        } else {
            alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try debuging your mobile phone from `chrome://inspect/#devices`. Maybe there you find what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for  the reply, works fine via browser on the mobile phone but the Phonegap compilation fails.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764852/get-facebook-user-profile-using-cordova/36765196#36765196

Comment: Neither, thinks it might have to do with permissions.