# Cordova Facebook login doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, oauth

No problems logging in through the application on my desktop browser, but the script can't run properly on my Android phone.

I have already added these plugins:

- https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

But it still doesn't work. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You’re missing that “it doesn’t work” is not a proper problem description. Please go read [ask].

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764852/get-facebook-user-profile-using-cordova/36765196#36765196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when using Cordova, the login had to be initiated with a call to `facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure)` and I can't just use the usual web login.

So sorry for the trouble.